# write multiple statistics analysis into the same output file with arcpy

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy

How can I add multiple stats from the arcpy.Statistics_analysis to a single output file. Can I create a text file instead of a table ?

Using one of the examples in [help.arcgis](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001z000000), if I add other stat analysis, what is the best way to work with the output?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:/data/Habitat_Analysis.gdb"
arcpy.Statistics_analysis("futrds", "C:/output/output.gdb/stats1", [["Shape_Length", "SUM"]], "NM")
arcpy.Statistics_analysis("futrds", "C:/output/output.gdb/stats2", [["Shape_Length", "MEAN"]], "NM")
arcpy.Statistics_analysis("futrds", "C:/output/output.gdb/stats3", [["Shape_Length", "STD"]], "NM")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the look of page you linked to, you can get several summary statistics in one go. Have you tried:

```py
arcpy.Statistics_analysis("futrds", "C:/output/output.gdb/stats1", [["Shape_Length", "SUM"],["Shape_Length", "MEAN"],["Shape_Length", "STD"]], "NM")
```

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001z000000

As far as creating a text file, it doesn't look like it but you could always open the table later and then write it out to a text file. Python makes it pretty easy to work with cursors and text files.